# Help with conmutator identity with angular momentum and vector

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, vectors, linear-algebra

I need to prove this identity:

$ [ \textbf{J}^2,  \textbf{J}\times  \textbf{V}] = 2i\hbar( \textbf{J}^2 \textbf{V} - ( \textbf{J} \cdot  \textbf{V}) \textbf{J}) $

Where $ \textbf{J}$ is an angular momentum and $ \textbf{V}$ is a vector operator that satisfies $[J_i, V_j] = i\hbar \epsilon_{ijk} V_k$. Any advice? I noted that the right side is $ \textbf{J} \times ( \textbf{V} \times  \textbf{J})$, but been trying for hours and I'm stuck.

Comment: This is an expression with just one free vector index. You *are* aware of identities involving two Levi-Civita tensors, right?

Comment: yes I am, I never used them thought.

Comment: Write your expression in tensor/index form, and evaluate the composite commutators.